# Simple way to connect Ubuntu Mate to Mac?

Tags: networking, samba, mac, mate

I have a new Apple Macintosh computer and I am trying to find a way to send files back and forth from my Ubuntu Mate laptop. I have no Windows machines in my network. I don't know much about modern Macs.

I have turned on File sharing on the Mac and have done the funny thing about the password:
[image]

In System Preferences->Network->WiFi->Advanced...->WINS
I have set the Workgroup to "HOME".

In caja on the Ubuntu Mate, I can use the Browse Network bookmark and the name of the Mac appears. If I double-click on the Mac's icon, I get a dialogue box that says:

[image: Screenshot at 2021-04-25 19:23:22]

I correct the Domain name to the workgroup that the Mac is using, type the password of my user on the Mac and click "Connect".
The dialogue box goes away and then comes back with the Domain name reverted to WORKGROUP and waits for the password again. (N.B. I notice that the Mac username has a capital B. Important?)

Am I doing something wrong?

Is there a simpler way of doing file sharing between the two computers?

Later: Samba is running out of the box (I think) on the Ubuntu Mate. After I had edited /etc/samba/smb.conf to use HOME as Workgroup, allow access to users home directories and then restarted smbd and run the smbpasswd command, I was able to access my files on UM from the Mac.

I wasn't really expecting that file sharing would not be a GUI activity.

I'm still failing to connect to the Mac from UM, so more info later.

Answer (score 2):

What is missing from your description is adding your Mac user to the smb password database on the Mac.

After you go to **Sharing** > enable **File Sharing** click on the **Options** button > then enable your Mac user name.

Now go back to caja and enter the Mac users password.

Don't obsess about the workgroup / domain.

Comment: Thanks. I had already enabled my Mac username. I have edited my question to make that clear. Also added some output that suggests Samba is running on the Ubuntu. Does that make it a Samba server?

Comment: Samba is not running (Active: inactive (dead)). But you don't need a samba server to connect to the mac. Did you try passing Bob as the user name?

Comment: You stated you have a "new" apple mac so I assumed you were running Big Sur. Big Sur has no AFP option for file sharing. What version of MacOS are you running?

Comment: It looks like Samba runs out of the box on Ubuntu. Once I had edited workgroup to HOME in /etc/samba/smb.conf (and in the Mac set the WINS server to the ip address of the Ubuntu) I was able to connect from Mac to Ubuntu as Guest. Still having problems with the password for registered user. See my further question.

Comment: Yes, the Mac is new-to-me. It's MacOS 10.15.7 (Catalina).

Answer (score -1):

Try installing Samba on your Ubuntu MATE machine, and sharing folders to your Mac that way. Also, you don't need a dedicated Samba server. Just using your existing Ubuntu MATE machine will do.

Though you will need your Ubuntu MATE machine's local IP address in order to connect your Mac to it (and they will both need to be on the same network. Just open up a terminal and type `ip a`. The (local) IP address you want will be under the interface beginning with either "enp" (if you are using Ethernet) or "wlp" (if you are using Wi-Fi).

Comment: The command "whereis samba" gives:
"samba: /usr/sbin/samba /usr/lib/samba /etc/samba /usr/share/samba /usr/share/man/man7/samba.7.gz /usr/share/man/man8/samba.8.gz" Does that mean it is installed? Same network and I know the ip addresses and also the .local names. You are suggesting I try to access Mate from Mac instead of the other way round?

Comment: It appears that Samba is installed. And yes, I am suggesting accessing Ubuntu MATE from your Mac. I feel that it's a better implementation than the other way around.

Comment: Thanks. Samba is running out of the box (I think) on the Ubuntu Mate. After I had edited /etc/samba/smb.conf to use HOME as Workgroup, allow access to users home directories and then restarted smbd and run the smbpasswd command, I was able to access my files on UM from the Mac.